# Обработка исключений, инициированных в Invoke

Tags: c#, исключения, рефлексия, try-catch

Существует именованное исключение предметной области `DomainException`.

```
public class DomainException : Exception { }
```

Существует класс `Foo`, у которого есть метод `Throw`, пробрасывающий `DomainException`.

```
public class Foo
{
    public void Throw()
    {
        throw new DomainException();
    }
}
```

Существует класс, который вызывает у экземпляра `Foo` метод `Throw` через рефлексию.

```
public static class FooManager
{
    public static void InvokeThrow(object foo)
    {
        var methodInfo = typeof(Foo).GetMethod("Throw");
        methodInfo.Invoke(foo, null);
    }
}
```

Существует кусок кода, который вызывает `InvokeThrow` и пытается поймать и обработать `DomainException`.

```
try
{
    FooManager.InvokeThrow(new Foo());
}
catch(DomainException ex)
{
    //Do something cool.
}
```

Желаемое данный кусок кода не сделает, потому что [`Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx) оборачивает внутренние исключения в [`TargetInvocactionException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.reflection.targetinvocationexception(v=vs.110).aspx). Искомое `DomainException` окажется в [`InnerException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.exception.innerexception(v=vs.110).aspx) реально пробрасываемого исключения.

**Вопрос:** как поймать и обработать именно `DomainException`?

*Варианты:*

1 Обернуть вызов `Invoke` в `try-catch` и пробрасывать `InnerException`.

```
public static void InvokeThrow(object foo)
{
    try
    {
        var methodInfo = typeof(Foo).GetMethod("Throw");
        methodInfo.Invoke(foo, null);
     }
     catch(TargetInvocationException ex)
     {
         throw ex.InnerException;
     }
}
```

Вариант плох по той простой причине, что получим стэк исключения, заканчивающийся на `InvokeThrow`.

Есть ощущение, что я упускаю здесь что-то очень простое.

Есть ли какой-то умный и/или элегантный способ поймать это исключение/вызвать метод не через `Invoke`/получить нормальный стэк при пробрасывании `InnerException`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В .NET 4.5 есть класс [`ExceptionDispatchInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.exceptiondispatchinfo.aspx), позволяющий перебрасывать чужие исключения с сохранением call stack:

```
try
{
    var methodInfo = typeof(Foo).GetMethod("Throw");
    methodInfo.Invoke(foo, null);
}
catch(TargetInvocationException ex)
{
    ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex.InnerException).Throw();
    // throw; <--- раскомментировать если метод не-void, ради успокоения компилятора
}
```

`ExceptionDispatchInfo` был добавлен ради поддержки `async`/`await` - они таким образом перебрасывают обернутые в `AggregateException` исключения из сгенерированных Task-ов.